# Размер папки node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, express, fs

Мне нужен размер папки node js. Я понимаю, что у самой папки нет свойства size. Пробовал делать так:

```
const fs = require('fs')
...
app.get("/size", (req, res) => {
var size = 0;
var files = fs.readdirsync("./data")
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
fs.stat(`./data/${files[i]}`, (er, result) => {
if (er) throw er;
size += result.size;
})
}
console.log(size)
```

но он всё равно выводил 0. В папке файлы есть. Я понимаю, что здесь виновата асинхронность колбэков, но что делать? Файлов может быть разное количество

Comment: Через statSync тоже пробовал, не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Всё, я разобрался. Надо было:

```
app.get("/size", (req, res) => {
var size = 0;
files = fs.readDirSync("./data");
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
size += fs.statSync(`./data/${files[i]}`).size;
}
console.log(size)
})
```